# Rendering issue : failed to load rendering issue library

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THanK.png)

Currently i have using android studio 2.1.2, there is a problem of layout design,there is only xml file for layout not design,there is a message display 
"Rendering problem library is missing".

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, you have problem with the location of the Android Studio/SDK, move or even better install Android Studio/SDK to the new destination.

You current path is 
**C:/Users/Shivam Goyal/AppData/Local/Android/SDK**

And you should have something without blank space in destination path for example:
**C:/Android/SDK**